# Compact quasi-coherent sheaves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, schemes, compactness, quasi-coherent-modules

Let $X$ be a scheme. What are the compact objects in the category of quasi-coherent $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules? All references seem to discuss the derived category but I need the abelian category.

Comment: Meta discussion here:  https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/4200/flood-of-new-users

Answer (score 2):

$\DeclareMathOperator\colim{colim}\DeclareMathOperator\Qch{Qch}\DeclareMathOperator\Coh{Coh}\DeclareMathOperator\Hom{Hom}\newcommand\Ab{\mathrm{Ab}}\newcommand\Id{\mathrm{Id}}$In a category admitting small filtrant inductive limits, we call an object $X$  compact if $\Hom(X,\cdot)$ commutes with small filtrant inductive limits. Let
$X$ be a  Noetherian scheme. Then $F$ is a compact object of $\Qch(O_X)$ iff $F\in \Coh(O_X)$.

Proof (similar to that of https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0G8P) learned from a friend: Let $\colim_iG_i$ be a filtered colimit in $\Qch(O_X)$.

Step 1. We prove that $O_X$ is compact: Because the underlying topology of $X$ is locally Noetherian, by  [Stacks 01FF](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01FF),  the canonical map $\colim_i\Gamma(X,G_i)\to \Gamma(X,\colim_iG_i)$ is an isomorphism.

Step 2. If $O_X^n\to O_X^m\to F\to0$ is an exact sequence, then there is a commutative diagram with exact rows
$$\require{AMScd}\begin{CD}
0 @>>> \colim_i \Hom(F, G_i) @>>> \colim_i \Hom(O_X^m, G_i) @>>> \colim_i \Hom(O_X^n, G_i) \\
@. @VVV @VVV @VVV \\
0 @>>> \Hom(F, \colim_i G_i) @>>> \Hom(O_X^m, \colim_i G_i) @>>> \Hom(O_X^n, \colim_i G_i)
\end{CD}$$
([TikzCD link](https://tikzcd.yichuanshen.de/#N4Igdg9gJgpgziAXAbVABwnAlgFyxMJZABgBpiBdUkANwEMAbAVxiRGJAF9T1Nd9CKAIzkqtRizYBjCAywBbAPpYAEhHkAKAGKkA4soCUXHiAzY8BIgCZR1es1aIQMuUtXqNAeUUANAHryeobGvOYCRADMtuIO0rIKymqa3v5gQVhG3KH8lihkQmL2kk4cWaZ8FoLIIgV2Eo4gSdqkLglY+hkh5WG5yDa1McWNHikBLfFuHZkmZjlVUQNFDU2jaa2TwZxiMFAA5vBEoABmAE7qSGQgOBBIIoOOYEwMDNQMdABGMAwAChXhTgwYEccF1TudEHdrkgbPckI9nq8Pl9fj1BCBAcDQWd5LdqFDEABWOqxRDwl7opE-P65dFAkFlME4xAw-FRWGkp7kt6fKmotgY+kmRnQvE3RAANmJxTJiJ5KLm-LpWPBbPxAHYpQ9ObLkdS0QLlUyACyipBE9kyilyvWKzEM7Fm00SzVw7VW3V8gFK+3gyVXMUai1u7kehVeu0UThAA)).
The two vertical homomorphisms on the right are isomorphisms, so is the vertical one on the left.

Step 3. Assume that $F\in \Coh(O_X)$, then there is an open cover $\{U_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha}$ of $X$ s.t. for every $\alpha$, there is an exact sequence $O_X^{n_{\alpha}}\rvert_{U_{\alpha}}\to O_X^{m_{\alpha}}\rvert_{U_{\alpha}}\to F\rvert_{U_{\alpha}}$. Since the category $\Ab$ satisfies AB5, $\colim_i\Hom(F,G_i)$ is the equalizer of the two natural maps $\prod_{\alpha}\colim_i\Hom(F\rvert_{U_{\alpha}},G_i)\rightrightarrows \prod_{\alpha,\beta}\colim_i\Hom(F\rvert_{U_{\alpha}\cap U_{\beta}},G_i)$. The following commutative diagram has exact rows
$$\begin{CD}
0 @>>> \colim_i \Hom(F, G_i) @>>> \prod_\alpha \colim_i \Hom(F\rvert_{U_\alpha}, G_i) @>>> \prod_{\alpha, \beta} \colim_i \Hom(F\rvert_{U_\alpha \cap U_\beta}, G_i) \\
@. @VVV @VVV @VVV \\
0 @>>> \Hom(F, \colim_i G_i) @>>> \prod_\alpha \Hom(F\rvert_{U_\alpha}, G_i) @>>> \prod_{\alpha, \beta} \Hom(F\rvert_{U_\alpha \cap U_\beta}, \colim_i G_i)
\end{CD}$$
([TikzCD link](https://tikzcd.yichuanshen.de/#N4Igdg9gJgpgziAXAbVABwnAlgFyxMJZABgBpiBdUkANwEMAbAVxiRGJAF9T1Nd9CKAIzkqtRizYBjCAywBbAPpYAEhHkAKAGKkA4soCUXHiAzY8BIgCZR1es1aIQAHWdoATtEXBXjNAAs6Thk5JVV1bQAfbwBVb18GAKDufSwjbl5zASIAZltxBzZXDy8fZz9A0lcAIxgcIJCFZTVNLWjgOLKKoNcpOjQAAk6auuS9Q2NM-ksUMiExe0knDgzTPgtBZBF5uwlHEBbtUkaw1PSTM2nNmx2CpZc3Tyh48sTAzkO22Jfuzm4T5RnSZrLIzZB5W6LfbFJ4-N50KrOWr1D4RL4dOFJTi9fpDF7IsYArBAzhiGBQADm8CIoAAZp55EgyCAcBAkCI7o4wEwGAxqAw6LUGAAFdbZJwMGC0nDA+nqdnUVlIGycpDc3n8wUwEVimYgSXS2UMhUstmIACsu0KiHVfP1Wp1oME+qlMtWcsZiBVSsQeVVNp5doFQtFTrYBrdJg9ysVZoAbFalrbNSHdc6I0b5b7Y0gAOyJrmBlPa0NXcOuzOegAsOYtBbVRftqbDEor7uNddNSAT-uTTZLafLhvbWZ7PvzvcbwYHLZdw4onCAA)).
By last paragraph, the natural map $\colim_i\Hom(F|_{U_{\alpha}},G_i\rvert_{U_{\alpha}})\to \Hom(F\rvert_{U_{\alpha}},(\colim_iG_i)\rvert_{U_{\alpha}})$ is an isomorphism.  Hence, the two vertical homomorphisms on the right are isomorphisms, so is the vertical one on the left. This proves that $F$ is compact.

Step 4. Conversely, assume that $F$ is a compact object. By a result of Deligne (Proposition 2, p.407 of *[Residues and duality](https://doi.org/10.1007/BFb0080482)* by Hartshorne), $F=\colim_iF_i$ is a filtrant colimit of a family of coherent modules $\{F_i\}$. Then $\Hom(F,F)=\Hom(F,\colim_i F_i)=\colim_i\Hom(F,F_i)$, so there is $i_0\in I$ and $\iota:F\to F_{i_0}$ st $r\iota=\Id_F$, where $r:F_{i_0}\to F$ is the canonical morphism. Then $r$ is surjective, so $F$ is finite type. For every open subset $U$ of $X$, every $n\ge 1$, the kernel of $f:O_X^n\rvert_U\to F\rvert_U$ is the kernel of $\iota f:O_X^n\rvert_U\to F_{i_0}\rvert_U$. Then the kernel has finite type. Thus, $F$ is coherent.

Comment: @LSpice, Your efforts and time are much appreciate. I am not good at adding links and diagrams. Thank you for correcting my mistakes!